# LSTM, pattern and noise gap

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I want to find sequence patterns in a time series with random noise gap.

For example, this is the pattern I wan to find:

**1, 2, 3, 4**

But, my samples are:

```
    *1*, 10,         *2*,             *3*, 11, 12, *4*
    *1*,             *2*, 10, 14, 15, *3*, 10, 13, *4*
10, *1*, 10, 10, 10, *2*, 11, 12,     *3*,         *4*
```

I don't know that the "good" elements are 1, 2, 3 and 4.

I started with a LSTM decoder, but "the noise" hide the good elements. For example, with the 3 samples, I get:

```
*1*, 10, 13, 10, ...
```

and 2, 3 and 4 are hidden

Have you an idea to find those patterns ?

Thanks.

Frédéric

Comment: my goal is to generate this pattern from those samples

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point you can use a sequence-to-sequence ([seq2seq](https://github.com/farizrahman4u/seq2seq)) model. The linked repo has nice explanation how these models work and what type of problems they cover. The crucial point would be how to encode your sequence. Often they are encoded as one-hot vectors. So if you have a fixed upper bound on the number of distinct numbers/items in your sequence you can use it.

Instead of generating a new sequence without noise from the original one, you can also try to classify each point as noise or not and eliminate those classified as noise as your output. Something along the lines of:

```
seq = Input(shape=(timesteps, features))
hidden = LSTM(HIDDEN_UNITS, return_sequences=True)(seq)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))(hidden)
```

You will have to know before hand whether each data point is noise or not.

Comment: hi, thanks for your response. I use a seq2seq model to generate the sequence, but I have different samples of sequence, and all are good. I just when to generate a "compatible" sequence but with difference of element or the order; after training, the network seems to memorize the more frequent item for a position in the sequence